# Does cracking knuckles (or any other joints) lead to arthritis? Or is this a medical myth?

Tags: contributing-factors, fingers, osteoarthritis, knuckles, medical-myths

Growing up, my grandmother always told us kids: "Don't crack your knuckles it will lead to arthritis in your fingers." And then she would show us her arthritic fingers as "proof" of the aftermath. However, I heard that this may be a medical myth. Can someone either confirm or deny the harmful effects of cracking one's knuckles?

Comment: Lifelong knuckle cracker here. I was told that all my life. Still waiting for the arthritis. My wife never cracks hers, and she has arthritis in her hands. Just anecdote....

Comment: @CareyGregory - That was my understanding as well, that arthritis was hereditary. You can't get it from cracking knuckles, but cracking knuckles can make it worse if you *do* get it.